# Reset form control with dynamic form names

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to reset a select form control within a dynamically created form. The name of the form control will be dynamic and different each time. How do I pass on the control name to the reset method in order to give the control a default value when it is reset instead of it being set to null. The code below does not seem to pick up the controlName within the reset method.

```
resetForm() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.storedFieldNames.length; i++) {
      console.log(this.form);
      const controlName = this.storedFieldNames[i];
      const controlVal = this.storedFieldVals[i];
      this.form.reset({
        controlName: controlVal
      });
    }
  }
```

I expect the form to reset and all select values to have a default selected value of the original default. At the moment it resets the form but the values are null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save your original form value, and when calling reset, simply pass that original value.

```
constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {
  this.someForm = fb.group({ ... });
  this.initialValue = this.someForm.value;
}

reset() {
  this.someForm.reset(this.initialValue);
}
```

Looks way cleaner and more understandable, don't you think ?

Comment: Thank you, worked perfect and much cleaner I agree :)